# Converting access db to sql using mdbtools

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, mdbtools

While I was trying to import my .accdb to sql database by using command

```
mdb-schema IPEDS201617.accdb | mysql -u root -p IPED201617
```

It is throwing an error which says

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 11: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[ADM2016]
(
    [UNITID]            Long Integer,
    [ADMCON1]            Integer,
    [ADMCON2]            Inte' at line 1
```

I thought it is a datatype error so I converted all long integer to text but the error still persists.

I simply want to get ***SQL* DB** from ***.accdb*** So if there is any way to do that directly.**

Comment: You don't show your SQL - and error message indicates it is `in the syntax to use near '[ADM2016]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% mdb-schema db.accdb mysql > schema.sql

% mdb-tables -1 db.accdb | xargs -I {} -n 1 mdb-export -D '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -I mysql db.accdb {} > data.sql
```

This will create Schema and data sql files seprately.